# Remove need for encrypted password for twitter logins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, omniauth, ruby-2.0

I’d like to know how I can create a new user using a twitter account with devise (and omniauth) and not require an “Encrypted password”? 
I was able to remove having to provide a password by adding (to my user model):

```
def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?   
end
```

How do I do the same for encrypted passwords?

I’m following along with Ryan Bates RailsCasts episode #235 [Devise and OmniAuth (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised)

I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2.0 and the "omniauth-twitter" gem. On a windows machine.